# Turtlebot simulator laser scan not working

Tags: gazebo, simulation, rviz, turtlebot, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,
I'm learning ROS and I'm trying to follow this tutorial link: http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_simulator/Tutorials/hydro/Explore%20the%20Gazebo%20world, when I put several objects in the gazebo, and ran the command
**roslaunch turtlebot_rviz_launchers view_robot.launch**. I expected to see the laser sensor and camera can read this and show their information in the Rviz, however it just gave me a blank screen without any sensory information. The image doesn't work properly either. Anybody has any ideas ? I'm using ubuntu 12.04, ROS Hydro, and gazebo 1.9.6. The global fixed frame is "base_link", the laserscan topic is /scan, and the image topic is /camera/depth/image_raw and /camera/rgb/image_raw

Thanks very much !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/212802/turtlebot-simulator-laser-scan-not-working./) by [yizheng](https://answers.ros.org/users/22954/yizheng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-07-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm also use ROS Hydro.
I can work by following instruction:

```
export TURTLEBOT_BASE=create
export TURTLEBOT_STACKS=circles
export TURTLEBOT_3D_SENSOR=asus_xtion_pro
optirun roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_playground.launch
```

You can have a try~

Sam

---

Originally posted by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) with karma: 2570 on 2017-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0